# Hide Button in HomeView after successful Login

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, uibutton

I have two buttons (`btnHome` and `btnProfile`) in `HomeView`. After successful login same `HomeView` is displayed but `btnProfile` should be hidden.

Comment: are you working in swift ? ya objective c

Comment: It's good & common practice (in line with iOS naming) to not abbreviate. Also it's very common to put the type name last. So you should consider names: `homeButton` and `profileButton`.

Comment: Objective-C……..

Comment: @Abhimanyu check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can save **flag** of **success login** action to `NSUserDefaults` and **check** it in `viewWillAppear` method. Example of your `UIViewController`:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    let btnProfile = UIButton()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let hasLoginAction = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "success_login")
        btnProfile.isHidden = hasLoginAction
    }

    func login() { 
        //just example, your logic logic here
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "success_login")
    }
}
```

`Objective-C` version:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnProfile;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    BOOL hasLogin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"success_login"];
    self.btnProfile.hidden = hasLogin;
}

- (void)login {
    //just example, your logic logic here
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"success_login"];
}


@end
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, there's a `}` sticking out now.

Comment: In objective-C please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LoginSuccess"] == YES)
    {
      //button hide 
      profile.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

When you log in Success at that time set a `NSUserDefaults` value .

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"LoginSuccess"];
```